# MongoDB aggregate error: expression must have exactly one field

Tags: mongodb

I have the following collection:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5c3f744a0f05e90001e0085a"),
  "date" : ISODate("2016-01-12T12:00:00.779Z"),
}
```

I need to **group** my documents by **WEEK** so I came up with this solution:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group : {
      _id: { $year: { date: '$date' }, $week: { date: '$date' } },
      date: { $first: '$date' }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: { date: -1 }
  }
]);
```

But when I run this I get this error:

**An object representing an expression must have exactly one field: { $year: { date: "$date" }, $week: { date: "$date" } }**

How can this be fixed or is there any better solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Problem solved naming the expressions:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group : {
      _id: {
        year: { $year: { date: '$date' } },
        week: { $week: { date: '$date' } }
      },
      date: { $first: '$date' }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: { date: -1 }
  }
]);
```